# Passing Query Expression through Naviagtion Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, syntax-error, ms-access-forms

I have been practicing the use of building expressions through query design. I have created a custom search query using textfield's and a listbox from a form. Now if I run the query through the form it works. But when I run the query through the form after its been placed within navigation form it does not work. I receive the pop up window to input parameter values manually. I am trying to adjust the expression but cant seem to get the syntax correct.

[image]

Below is amended expression but still does not work

`[Forms]![Navigation Form Main]![Reports Form]![customerListBox]`

For clarification the report form is a tab within my navigation form and yes the expression is being called only when the reports form tab is selected.

Comment: What have you tried - something like `[Forms]![mainformname]![NavigationSubform]![startTextfield]`? Are search controls on main form or subform? I never use dynamic parameterized query. I also never use Navigation forms because they are more difficult to manipulate with code. Be aware even though you may see multiple tabs, only one form at a time is available. Forms are loaded/unloaded when tabs are clicked.

Comment: @June7 search controls are on a subform and yes the expression is called only when the reports form is open

Comment: Instead of `[Reports Form]`, try `[NavigationSubform]` which is default name of container holding [Reports Form].

Comment: @June7 Thank you so much your previous comment was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[Reports Form]`, try `[NavigationSubform]` which is default name of container holding `[Reports Form]`.